CUDA out of memory when training Llama-2-7b-hf model locally
I want to finetune meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf locally on my laptop. I am running out of CUDA memory when instantiating the Trainer class. I have 16Gb system RAM and a GTX 1060 with 6 Gb of GPU memory. I have split the model layers between cpu and gpu to keep the GPU from filling up and using a small batch size. However, when the trainer class is instantiated, the code again tries to fill the GPU and it runs out of memory. I tired some of the suggestions from Chat-GPT and used a custom trainer, used LoRA to decrease GPU memory footprint, still doesn't work. Is it possible to train "meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf" model locally? What am I missing below?
import pandas as pd
from datasets import load_dataset, Dataset
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification, TrainingArguments, Trainer, BitsAndBytesConfig, AutoConfig
import torch
from peft import get_peft_model, LoraConfig, TaskType
from transformers import DefaultDataCollator


import os
os.environ['PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF'] = 'max_split_size_mb:64'
os.environ['TRANSFORMERS_CACHE'] = '~/.cache/huggingface/transformers/'


##########################
class CustomTrainer(Trainer):
    def training_step(self, model, inputs):
        model.train()
        inputs = self._prepare_inputs(inputs)
        outputs = model(**inputs)
        loss = outputs.loss
        return loss

    def evaluation_step(self, model, inputs):
        model.eval()
        inputs = self._prepare_inputs(inputs)
        with torch.no_grad():
            outputs = model(**inputs)
        return outputs

    def _prepare_inputs(self, inputs):
        for k, v in inputs.items():
            if isinstance(v, torch.Tensor):
                device = gpu if 'input_ids' in k else cpu  # Adjust based on your logic
                inputs[k] = v.to(device)
        return inputs
##########################       
    
# Load your dataset
def load_data(train_path, val_path):
    train_df = pd.read_csv(train_path)
    val_df = pd.read_csv(val_path)

    train_dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(train_df)
    val_dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(val_df)

    return train_dataset, val_dataset

# Preprocess the data
def preprocess_function(examples, tokenizer, max_length=128):
    return tokenizer(examples['text'], padding='max_length', truncation=True, max_length=max_length)

# Main function to fine-tune the model
def fine_tune_model(model_name, train_dataset, val_dataset, output_dir, num_labels, local_model_path, num_train_epochs=3):

    # Load LLaMA tokenizer
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(local_model_path)
    tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
    tokenizer.padding_side = "right" # Fix weird overflow issue with fp16 training

    #tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
    #if tokenizer.pad_token is None:
    #    tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': '[PAD]'})
    
    tokenized_train = train_dataset.map(lambda x: preprocess_function(x, tokenizer), batched=True)
    tokenized_val = val_dataset.map(lambda x: preprocess_function(x, tokenizer), batched=True)

    quantization_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(llm_int8_enable_fp32_cpu_offload=True)
    device_map = {
        "transformer.wte": "cpu",
        "transformer.h": "cuda",
        "transformer.ln_f": "cpu",
        'model.embed_tokens': 'cuda',
        'model.encoder': 'cpu',
        'model.decoder': 'cuda',
        "lm_head": "cpu",
        "model.layers": "cuda",
        "model.norm": "cuda",
        "score": "cuda"
    }
    
    config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(local_model_path)
    config.num_labels = num_labels
    config.device_map=device_map
    config.load_in_8bit=True
    config.llm_int8_enable_fp32_cpu_offload=True

    model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(local_model_path, config=config)
    
    
    for param in model.parameters():
        param.requires_grad = False
    
    # Add LoRA adapters for efficient fine-tuning
    peft_config = LoraConfig(
        task_type=TaskType.SEQ_CLS,
        r=8,
        lora_alpha=32,
        lora_dropout=0.1,
        bias="none",
    )
    model = get_peft_model(model, peft_config)
    model.print_trainable_parameters()  # Check the number of trainable parameters
    print(model)

    cpu = torch.device("cpu")
    gpu = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    
    for idx, layer in enumerate(model.base_model.model.model.layers):
        if idx % 5 == 0:
            layer.to(gpu)  # Move few layers to GPU
        else:
            layer.to(cpu)  # Move more layers to CPU

    # Verify device allocation
    for idx, layer in enumerate(model.base_model.model.model.layers[:10]):  # Checking the first 10 layers as an example
        print(f"Layer {idx} is on {next(layer.parameters()).device}")
        
    class CustomDataCollator(DefaultDataCollator):
        def __call__(self, features):
            batch = super().__call__(features)
            for key in batch:
                if isinstance(batch[key], torch.Tensor):
                    batch[key] = batch[key].to(gpu if 'input_ids' in key else cpu)  # Adjust based on your logic
            return batch
        
    data_collator = CustomDataCollator()


    training_args = TrainingArguments(
        output_dir=output_dir,
        eval_strategy="epoch",
        learning_rate=2e-5,
        per_device_train_batch_size=1,
        per_device_eval_batch_size=1,
        gradient_accumulation_steps=4,
        num_train_epochs=num_train_epochs,
        weight_decay=0.01,
    )
   

    trainer = CustomTrainer(
        model=model,
        args=training_args,
        train_dataset=tokenized_train,
        eval_dataset=tokenized_val,
        tokenizer=tokenizer,
        data_collator = data_collator
    )
    
    trainer.train()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    train_path = "workspace/learn_AI/llm_demo/train.csv"
    val_path = "workspace/learn_AI/llm_demo/validate.csv"
    model_name = "meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf"  
    local_model_path = str("local_directory/" + model_name)
    output_dir = "./results"
    num_labels = 2  # Number of classes in your classification task

    train_dataset, val_dataset = load_data(train_path, val_path)
    fine_tune_model(model_name, train_dataset, val_dataset, output_dir, num_labels, local_model_path)

I downloaded all the model files from the link https://huggingface.co/meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf/tree/main  into a local folder.
train.csv
text,labels
"I absolutely love this product! It works perfectly.",1
"The quality of this item is outstanding, highly recommend it.",1
"This is the worst purchase I've ever made. Completely useless.",0
"I am very dissatisfied with this product. It broke after one use.",0
"Fantastic experience! Will definitely buy again.",1
"Terrible customer service. I will not be buying from this store again.",0
"The delivery was quick and the product was as described. Very happy.",1
"The product arrived damaged and the return process was a nightmare.",0
"This item is okay, but it doesn't meet my expectations.",0
"Excellent quality and easy to use. Very satisfied.",1
"Awful experience, the product doesn't work as advertised.",0
"I love the design and functionality of this product. Great buy.",1
"Not worth the money. Very disappointed.",0
"Superb! Exactly what I was looking for.",1
"The product is decent, but the packaging was poor.",0
"Very pleased with my purchase. Highly recommend.",1
"Product stopped working after a week. Very frustrated.",0
"Best purchase I've made in a long time. Extremely happy.",1
"Would not recommend this product. It's a waste of money.",0
"Overall, a good product. Satisfied with my purchase.",1

validate.csv
text,labels
"This is a fantastic product. Exceeded my expectations.",1
"Very poor quality, not worth the money.",0
"Absolutely love it! Will recommend to friends.",1
"Completely dissatisfied with this item.",0
"Great value for the price. Happy with the purchase.",1
"The product did not work as expected. Disappointed.",0
"Wonderful experience, product arrived on time and works perfectly.",1
"Terrible quality. It broke within a few days.",0
"Satisfied with my purchase. Would buy again.",1
"Not what I expected. Very disappointed.",0
"Excellent product, great customer service.",1
"Regret buying this product. Total waste of money.",0
"Product is as described and works well. Happy customer.",1
"Product arrived late and was damaged. Very unhappy.",0
"Exceeded my expectations in every way. Fantastic!",1
"Low quality and poor performance. Do not recommend.",0
"Very pleased with the product. Will purchase again.",1
"Did not meet my expectations. Unsatisfied.",0
"Best product I've bought recently. Highly recommend.",1
"Terrible experience. Will not buy from this brand again.",0

